# Wrong clipping in glTF-model - AFrame

Tags: three.js, aframe

Video preview : https://i.imgur.com/VMhJV8v.mp4

I'm having clipping issues for quite some time now, not sure what causes this but so far the only solution is to move the object closer towards the camera and scale it down ( video preview link above )

I tried messing around with the camera clipping settings ( changed far / near values ). Played around with the 3d object transparency and container marker visibility ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666937/2496170)) - no dice , tried to change `renderOrder` ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666937/2496170)) , `frustumCulled` ([3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758692/2496170)) values recursively without any luck ...

- Using latest ARjs + Aframe image based markers with animated 3d models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue disappeared once I scaled down the image marker from 990x990 to 375x375 and reduced the a-entity scale value by the same ratio ( nailing down the position is still a bit tricky for different DPI devices )

¯\_(ツ)_/¯